# Overloaded function with params string[] in the signature

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have these two functions

```
    public static string Function1 (string id, params string[])
    {
       return Function1(id, null, null, params)
    }

public static string Function1 (string id, string id2, Object a, params string[])
{
      string id = id,
      if (IsValidId(id))
      {
            start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.Arguments = params;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id2)==false)
            {
                start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            }
      }
}
```

I want to use the second overload when I do the following call

```
MyStaticClaass.Function1(
        input1,
        input2,
        null, // (This one represents the Object)
        input3,
        input4,
        input5);
```

Is there a way I can force it to go to the second definition of the method?

The compilation error I have is: This call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: (and then the two methods above)

PS: I haven't chose to have these two functions. I can't change their signature or their names.

Comment: Hope that you are looking for overloading instead for overriding

Comment: I meant to say overloading... editing the post :)

Comment: In your example, the second definition *will* be used.

Comment: That's not what I see, it goes into the first definition

Comment: @user3587624 Can you include the *exact* code you're using? Your function definitions, for example, will not compile (`params string[]` is missing an identifier). Can you also provide the exact code you're using to invoke the method?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to create an overloading method here. all you need is a single method with signature like this, `public static string Function1 (params string[] args)`

Comment: Rob is right.In your example, the second definition will be used.

Comment: You'll need to cast the null to `object` when calling the method. For example: `... input2, (object)null, input3, ...`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot @Rob!

Comment: Like Rob said, you can cast the `null` to `object` to guarantee your desired behavior. That being said, I have to agree with everyone here - pasting the code you provided into Visual Studio produces no such error, and the second overload does get called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Named arguments` to overload a specific function like

```
 Program.Function1(
        id: input1,
        id2: input2,
        o:null,
        array: new string[] {input3,
            input4,
            input5});
```

and it will hit the function

```
public static string Function1 (string id, string id2, Object o, params string[] array)
{

}
```

for more detail you can check this [Named Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Making this as a valid answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this as well:

```
var result = Rootobject.Function1(
               "",
               "",
               null, // (This one represents the Object)
               new string[] { "", "", ""});
```

However, since you already know this is a fragile design or you wouldn't have ended here asking about it, perhaps you should rethink your overloads. Of course, we got it to work but it is not a good design.